# Laravel query select single column with multiple value matches

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Laravel query select single column with multiple value matches

```
$user = User::where('name', [
        'User1',
        'User2',
        'User3',
    ])->get();
```

Comment: use whereIn instead of where

Comment: Use `whereIn()` instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `whereIn()`:

```
$user = User::whereIn('name', ['User1', 'User2', 'User3'])->get();
```

`where()` is used for single values, but `whereIn()` uses an array to match against the given column.

Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses for full details.